# Nextcloud: Batch folder share for upload only

Tags: python, python-3.x, nextcloud

i want to create folders in my Nextcloud for many users.
The users should only be able to upload files.
That's why i wanted to write a script for that.
Here i found a [library for Python](https://github.com/Gsocol/pyncclient/blob/master/nextcloud_client/nextcloud_client.py) (like pyncclient) to create shares.
To test the script i first create folders named by timestamp.
With this folders i'm able to create shares, but the permission option is not working for me. I always only get read-only shares.
Could someone please help me how to do that right?

My script:

```
import nextcloud_client
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
nc = nextcloud_client.Client('http://domain.tld/nextcloud')
nc.login('user', 'password')
nc.mkdir(timestr)
link_info = nc.share_file_with_link(timestr, perms=4)
print("Here is your link: " + link_info.get_link())
```

Maybe there is a better library for that?
Thanks.

Edit:
I guess i found a workaround for the problem. I only need to update the permissions after i created the share:

```
nc.update_share(link_info.get_id(),perms=4)
```